# How to send email via python to several recipients with contacts on text file

Tags: python, email, smtplib

When I write the script below I get the error IndexError: list index out of range:

```
import smtplib

from string import Template

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

MY_ADDRESS = 'joaosoundcloudpython@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'XXXX'

def get_contacts(test1):
"""
Return two lists names, emails containing names and email addresses
read from a file specified by filename.
"""

names = []
emails = []
with open('/Users/joaopimenta/Documents/joaoPython/soundcloud_email.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as contacts_file:
    for a_contact in contacts_file:
        names.append(a_contact.split()[0])
        emails.append(a_contact.split()[100])
return names, emails

def read_template():
"""
Returns a Template object comprising the contents of the 
file specified by filename.
"""

with open(soundcloud_email_message.txt, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as template_file:
    template_file_content = template_file.read()
return Template(template_file_content)

def main():
names, emails = get_contacts('/Users/joaopimenta/Documents/joaoPython/soundcloud_email.rtf') # read contacts
message_template = read_template('/Users/joaopimenta/Documents/joaoPython/soundcloud_email_message.txt')

# set up the SMTP server
s = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587) 
s.starttls()
s.login(joaosoundcloudpython@gmail.com, XXXX)

# For each contact, send the email:
for name, email in zip(names, emails):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()       # create a message

    # add in the actual person name to the message template
    message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title())

    # Prints out the message body for our sake
    print(message)

    # setup the parameters of the message
    msg['From']=MY_ADDRESS
    msg['To']=email
    msg['Subject']="This is TEST"

    # add in the message body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    # send the message via the server set up earlier.
    s.send_message(msg)
    del msg

# Terminate the SMTP session and close the connection
s.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback so that we can see which line of code is raising that error?

Comment: The error means you are trying to access a list element by an index that does not exist. Could be this line: `a_contact.split()[100]`. The error should give you the exact line number, so you can then update the question.

Comment: Thanks surfer190!! TBH I used this code from a tutorial, I don't understand it 100% as I am a beginner with Python. Which index doesn't exist? I wrote test 1 in here : 
def get_contacts(test1) -> If the () are empty I get an error, when I wrote something it disappeared.

Comment: @myrtlecat Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Email_SeveralRecipients.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "Email_SeveralRecipients.py", line 36, in main
    names, emails = get_contacts('/Users/joaopimenta/Documents/joaoPython/soundcloud_email.rtf') # read contacts
  File "Email_SeveralRecipients.py", line 22, in get_contacts
    emails.append(a_contact.split()[100])
IndexError: list index out of range